# Salesforce Lightning: Controller functions interaction within the same component

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-chatter, salesforce-communities, salesforce-lightning

Do anyone know "how to call a lightning controller function from another function within the same lightning component?" 
Thanks
Aruna

```
    ({ 
    doInit: function(component, event, helper){

   var action = component.get("c.gettemps");
    action.setParams({ recordId : component.get("v.recordId") });
           action.setCallback(this, function(response){
       var parsedJSON= JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
       var size=component.get("v.limit");
       var counter = component.get("v.counter");
        component.set("{!v.myObject}",parsedJSON);



   var list=[];
        for(var i=0; i<size;i++)
        {
             list.push(parsedJSON[i]);
            counter++;

        }
               component.set("v.end",counter);
               component.set("{!v.counter}",counter);
               component.set("{!v.paginationList}",list);

        });
 $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

 next:function(component,event,helper)
{
    var myObject = component.get("v.myObject");
    var size=component.get("v.limit");
   var end = component.get("v.end");
    var counter = component.get("v.counter");
    var list=[];

    for(var i=end; i<end+size; i++)
    {
        if(i<myObject.length)
        {
            if(i>-1)
            {


        list.push(myObject[i]);
        counter++;
            }
        }

    } 
     component.set("v.end",counter);
     component.set("{!v.counter}",counter);
     component.set("{!v.paginationList}",list);  

},

previous:function(component,event,helper)
{

     var myObject = component.get("v.myObject");
    var size=component.get("v.limit");
    var end = component.get("v.end");
    var counter = component.get("v.counter");
           var list=[];
     for(var i=end-1; i>end-size-1; i--)
    {
        if(i>=-1)
        {

      list.push(myObject[i-1]);
        counter--;
         }


    }
     component.set("v.end",counter);
     component.set("{!v.counter}",counter);
     component.set("{!v.paginationList}",list);  
}   
 })
```

Actually I have problem with my previous function. When I stay in my first page and selects previous button my page should not be changed but my code is behaving abnormally. So I thought of reusing my doInit function to stay in the current page when I am already in the first page. Please help
Thanks
Aruna

Comment: Can you brief? and Sample code please..

Comment: Hi, I have updated my code. Please check

Comment: You should write your common methods in helper class and call that method.. I think you can check  before doing actions , you are in first page or not.

Answer (score 0):

In the helper it is possible by "this" operator

this.next();

In the controller you cannot do this directly.

But i have one solution for you :)

1. Create method handler in component .

2. Then you can call this method in controller and helper by componet.methodName function

component.triggerNextFun();

Comment: In the helper it is possible by "this" operator

this.next();

In the controller you cannot do this directly. 

But i have one solution for you :) 

1. Create method handler in component .

<aura:method name="triggerNextFun" action="{!c.next}"></aura:method> 

2. Then you can call this method in controller and helper by componet.methodName function


component.triggerNextFun();

Comment: Hi Praveen, Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this way

JS Controller :

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper){
        var action = component.get("c.getBeforeAWBDetails");

        action.setParams({
            "CaseId" : component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        console.log("caseId :" + component.get("v.recordId"));  

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(component.isValid() && state == "SUCCESS"){
                component.set("v.BeforeAWB", response.getReturnValue());
            } 
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    closeModal : function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
        var reInit = component.get("c.doInit");
// use this and extend the values you need to get from "doInit" method
        $A.enqueueAction(reInit);
    }
})
```